# Is it possible in C# make public virtual method private/internal in overriding class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

Say we have a:

```
class A {
 public virtual Do(){}
}
```

Can we create class `B` that overloads `A` so that its `Do` would be `private`/`protected`?

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: No, this is not possible in C#.

Comment: Since this appears to have been asked at least once before, I have to ask: why would you want to do this?  What would it be useful for?